# Iterate user input and convert to binary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a Binary counter program. I need it to print a decimal equivalent and the corresponding binary equivalent....

so far I have managed to get this  far , but I need to convert the binary from 0 up to the user input value, I have been playing around with it but I can't figure it out: Any help is appreciated :)

```
Please enter number: 12

Decimal: 1  = binary: 1100
Decimal: 2  = binary: 1100
Decimal: 3  = binary: 1100
Decimal: 4  = binary: 1100
Decimal: 5  = binary: 1100
Decimal: 6  = binary: 1100
Decimal: 7  = binary: 1100
Decimal: 8  = binary: 1100
Decimal: 9  = binary: 1100
Decimal: 10  = binary: 1100
Decimal: 11  = binary: 1100
Decimal: 12  = binary: 1100
```

From this code

```
dec = input('Please enter number')

new_list = []
index = 0
output = ''
counter = 0
dec = int(dec)
upper_range = int(dec)

#for x in range(0,upper_range):



while dec > 0:
        output += str(dec % 2)
        dec = (dec // 2)
output = output[::-1]

new_list.append(output)


while counter < upper_range:
    print('Decimal:', counter + 1, end=' ',)
    print(' = binary:' , *new_list)
    counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: `'{:04b}'.format(12)` converts `12` to a binary string with leading zeroes up to 4 characters: `'1100'`. you get  that part for free...

Comment: Thanks, but I have to convert using the code, I can't use the built in functions. Also the code itself works as a one off, but I want it to convert from 0 to user_input:)

Comment: you only calculate one single binary representation... the one for `dec`. that's what you sore in `new_list`. you should calculate that for every `counter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the decimal-to-binary conversion inside the loop instead; otherwise it only does the conversion of the upper bound value:

```
dec = input('Please enter number')

counter = 1
upper_range = int(dec)

while counter <= upper_range:
    binary = ''
    dec = counter
    while dec > 0:
        binary += str(dec % 2)
        dec = (dec // 2)
    binary = binary[::-1]
    print('Decimal:', counter, end=' ',)
    print(' = binary:' , binary)
    counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: I'd like to thank you for showing me that, I have much to learn.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct? (Click on the grey check mark next to the question to accept.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might answer your question.You can take help of built-in **bin** function or you can do it manually using the below **convTobin** method.

```
    #This is with the help of built-in
    n = int(input())
    for i in range(n+1):
        print('Decimal: ',i,' Binary: ',bin(i).split('b')[1]);

   #This is doing it manually
    n = int(input())

    def convTobin(num):
        if num == 0:
            return '0'
        s = ''
        while num:
            s = str(num&1) + s
            num = num>>1
        return s

    for i in range(n+1):
        print('Deciaml: ',i,'Binary: ',convTobin(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

n = int(input("Please enter number:"))

for i in range(1,n+1):

```
print "Decimal: "+str(i)+" = binary: "+str(format(i,'04b'))
```